# When reversing an array in c++, why do i get a "random" number in between an input and output?

Tags: c++, arrays

Up until now I've been studying C, and now i wanted to try C++. Started out with some easy tasks. But I can't seem to find the answer, why is there a number either 0 or 488834... printed out.

I've tried re-declaring variables, using

```
    for(n-1; n>=0; n--){
    cout << a[n] << endl;
  }

int main(){

  int var = 0;
  int a[100],n;
  cin >> n;

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin >> a[i];
    var++;
  }
  for(var-1; var>=0; var--){
    cout << a[var] << endl;
  }
```

Everything works, except that 0/some number in the middle of the output
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahejt.png)

Comment: in `for(var-1; var>=0; var--){ ` the part `var-1` does nothing. you are accessing `a[n]` which is undefined behavior. Since you did not initialize it.

Comment: don't edit the question to say that it's solved. Just clicking the checkmark is enough

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

`for(var-1; var>=0; var--){`

`var-1` doesn't actually modify the value of `var`. So `var` gets to keep its original value, which means the first value you end up printing is what is after the end of the original sequence.

Use `var = var - 1` instead.

Comment: Thank you, somehow i missed that. "-.-

Answer (score 1):

In your second for loop you don't have an assignment, just a statement. You start printing from a location of the array that contains an invalid number due to this, you may want too have your second loop read

```
for(var = var-1; var>=0; var--){
   cout << a[var] << endl;
}
```

Now, there are more element ways to write this, but this is a fix that is needed in your code.